# Error toast being shown in samsung devices stating screen touches might be delayed

Tags: android, android-keypad

I am getting the following error on Samsung S22 (Android OS 12) when the keypad is opened in my app. Please let me know how to resolve this if anyone has been able to figure it out.

I tried with other devices on Android 12,lower and higher as well but didn't get the error toast.

[image]

Comment: What is your `minSdk` and `targetSdk`?

Comment: can you share the code for the underlying inputfield that prompts the keypad